# Excel Get minimum value, and If two cells match from a row, return values from the consecutive 3 columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Here's a simple explanation of what I'm having trouble with.

Get minimum value, and If two cells match from a row, return values from the consecutive 3 columns.

---

**SUPPLIER A**

- **F4:** PRICES SUPPLIER A
- **G4:** SUPPLIER A NAME
- **H4:** LEAD TIME SUPPLIER  A
- **I4:**  BRAND SUPPLIER A

---

**SUPPLIER B**

- **J4:** PRICES SUPPLIER B
- **K4:** SUPPLIER B NAME
- **L4:** LEAD TIME SUPPLIER  B
- **M4:** BRAND SUPPLIER B

---

**SUPPLIER C**

- **N4:** PRICES SUPPLIER C,
- **O4:** SUPPLIER C NAME,
- **P4:** LEAD TIME SUPPLIER  C
- **Q4:**  BRAND SUPPLIER C

On the first Table I need to get the SMALLEST price provided by the 3 suppliers, and save

- B4: The smallest price from the 3 suppliers
- C4: The consecutive 2nd column from the supplier selected with the SUPPLIER NAME (The name of the supplier with lower price)
- D4: The consecutive 3rd column from the supplier selected with the SUPPLIER LEAD TIME (The lead time of the supplier with lower price)
- E4: The consecutive 4rd column from the supplier selected with the SUPPLIER BRAND (The brand of the supplier with lower price

See attached screenshot here for more details: click
[excel photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymxhE.png)

Comment: Really Thanks so much! I been hours with this issue And You just solved in 2min. Really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In B4:

```
=MIN($F4,$J4,$N4)
```

Then in C4:

```
=INDEX($F4:$Q4,MATCH($B4,$F4:$Q4,0)+COLUMN(A:A))
```

And copy over through E4

Comment: Hello, i have a question. On the first calculation in B4, How you get the minimum excluding 0? or 0,0000?

Comment: Sorry that the other day i put thanks in my post instead of here, because i was not very familiar with the platform! thanks so much for your help!!!

Comment: I think i already could make correct: 
=SMALL(($F4;$J4;$N4);INDEX(FREQUENCY(($F4;$J4;$N4);0);1)+1)
Thanksss!!!!